# Ampscript dateformat to display date in format (eg. 12th July 2017 or 1st July 2017 or 2nd July 2017 )

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can anyone tell me if there is a dateformat function in ampscript which will display date in the following format:
1st July 2017
Or
2nd July 2017
Or
3rd July 2017

For month wiht full name i know we can use'MMMMM' in format. smae for year 'yyyy' or'yyy'. 
But for the day to have st/nd/rd/th (like 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th) is there any predefined functions ?

Comment: Have you tried googling this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is and it is called `FormatDate`. Additionally you can use `Format`. Adding *st/nd/rd/th* can be done by saving the value of the day in a variable and then checking it using *IF THEN ELSEIF* constructs for example. To reuse this, you could save this AMPscript-code to a Code Snippet.

**Saving the day to a variable:**

```
%%[
    Var @day, @YourFormattedDayString
    Set @day = Format(Now(), "d")

    /* check the value of d like this: */

    IF @day == 1 THEN
        Set @YourFormattedDayString = Concat(@day, "st")
    ELSEIF @day == 2 THEN
        Set @YourFormattedDayString = Concat(@day, "nd")
    ELSE
        /* do the rest of the work using multiple else ifs */
    ENDIF
]%%
```

**FormatDate-Example:**

```
%%=FormatDate("2012-10-05 13:21:34.567890", "MMM dd, yyyy", "HH:mm:ss.tt", "en-US")=%%
```

**Format-Example:**

```
%%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
```

**Related Documentation:**

- [AMPscript Date and Time Formatting](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_date_and_time_formatting/)
- [Format(1,2)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/format/#format)
- [FormatDate(1,2,3,4)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/formatdate/#formatdate)
- [AMPscript Language Elements](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_langauge_elements/)

Comment: Here's a complete list of the number suffix handling in AMPScript: https://sprignaturemoves.com/number-suffixes-in-ampscript/